# v-model on existing data from external api

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

ran into a bit of an issue.

I'm running a next js frontend with a laravel + inertia custom cms, I have my next js app setup so that I can read translation files via an API call to display inside of the cms.

E.g. I have a `TranslationsAPI.php` file which contain a few functions, one of these is called `getTranslations` whih looks like this

```
    public function getTranslations(string $locale, string $file): mixed
    {
        $data = [];

        $response = Http::get(config('app.frontend_url') . 'api/read-translations?locale=' . $locale . '&file=' . $file);

        if ($response->successful()) {
            $data = $response->json();
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

if one where to set the locale param to `en-US` and the file param to `common.json`, this function would return a json object containing the follow data:

```
{
  "intro": "NOT_TRANSLATED",
  "new": "NOT_TRANSLATED",
  "info": "NOT_TRANSLATED",
  "back": "NOT_TRANSLATED",
  "touch": "NOT_TRANSLATED",
  "name": "NOT_TRANSLATED",
  "email": "NOT_TRANSLATED",
  "message": "NOT_TRANSLATED",
  "send": "NOT_TRANSLATED",
  "copyright": "NOT_TRANSLATED",
  "about": "NOT_TRANSLATED",
  "contact": "NOT_TRANSLATED",
  "change-locale": "NOT_TRANSLATED",
  "errorFetching": "NOT_TRANSLATED",
  "loadingFetching": "NOT_TRANSLATED"
}
```

Now inside of my `TranslationsController` I call this method

```
    public function index(Request $request): Response
    {

        if ($request->input('language')) {
            return Inertia::render('Translations/index', [
                'translations' => $this->getTranslations->getTranslations($request->input('language'), $request->input('file')),

            ]);
        }

        return Inertia::render('Translations/index', [
            'translations' => $this->getTranslations->getTranslations('nl-NL', 'common.json'),
        ]);
    }
```

and display it inside of my vue component

```
    props: {
        translations: {
            type: Object,
            default: null
        },

        files: {
            type: Object,
            default: null
        }
    },
```

and render it as inputs

```
                    <div v-if="translations" class="flex flex-col my-2" v-for="(value,index) in translations">
                        <div :key="index" class="form-control">
                            <div class="relative my-2 items-center justify-center flex">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Your translation string"
                                       name="translation-key"
                                       class=" pr-16 input input-primary input-bordered mx-2" :value="index"/>

                                <input type="text" placeholder="Your translation string"
                                       name="translation-value"
                                       class=" pr-16 input input-primary input-bordered mx-2" :value="value"/>
                                <button type="button"
                                        class="absolute top-0 right-0 rounded-l-none btn btn-error no-animation"
                                        @click="removeInput(index)">delete
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And this is where my problem arises,I can add new translations and delete existing ones. But I'm not sure how to properly wire up a `v-model` to the existing translations so that they can be edited and updated.

Basically something like

```
  <input type="text" placeholder="Your translation string"
         name="translation-key"
         v-model="somethinghere" <--- this needs to be a v-model to update the existing translations
         class=" pr-16 input input-primary input-bordered mx-2" 
         :value="index"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly reference the object like so (`translations` is an object like in your example):

```js
<input
    type="text"
    v-for="(item, key) in translations" v-model="translations[key]"
    :name="'translations[' + key + ']'"
/>
```

Note that you *cannot* use `v-model="item"` (the loop variable) since that refers to the local destructured variable in the loop. If you do that, basically nothing happens.

I've given a `name` to the input, but it depends on how you are going to save the form, since you can submit the form normally and have the browser handle it, or handle this in JavaScript by sending the `translations` object yourself in an AJAX request.